# Display Access Query Result in report

Tags: ms-access

I have a query in Access to calculate the percentage. It displays the desired result in the Datasheet View. When I try to put that result in a report using text box, it shows 0.

I have nine text boxes with different query results which also show their data in datasheet view. When it comes to report only one textbox shows a result, the others show 0.

I googled and found nothing. Every setting and formatting checked multiple times.

Query result in datasheet view
[image: Query result in datasheet view attached]

Report view using query result shows 0
[image: Report view using query result shows 0]

Comment: Did you validate that the report defines the fields as the same datatype as the datasheet view?

Comment: Yes, I did. Any other suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you have these textboxes in a report header or footer section which is displaying only first record data. Assuming this dataset has only these 5 records and you want them displayed as a single record in report, use `=Max([fieldname])` in each textbox - referencing appropriate fieldname of course.

If there are actually multiple groups of data, then put textboxes in a group section and use that same expression.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes it worked. But I am wondering that what does this Max function do. Will it consider full column data or the maximum value of the column data. Please clarify. Thanks again.

Comment: Perhaps you should research aggregate functions (and domain aggregate functions while you're at it). It returns maximum value of all values in specified column in report's RecordSource. If dataset is filtered, only records returned are considered.

Comment: Okay I am relatively new to Access so I really have no idea about aggregate functions. I will definitely check that. So 1 more question here. You said if dataset is filtered then only records returned are considered. So how can I put filter on that so that only record returns should be considered. Thank you for clarification and your help.

Comment: Put filter on what? The aggregate expression only considers records retrieved by report. You can put filter criteria in query or apply filter to report when opened. This is all basic Access functionality and any introductory tutorial book should have guidance.

Comment: Oh ok. I thought it's something different which I need to learn. I already placed the filter to report when opened. Thank you though.